# 301 redirect adding unnecessary query string to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, query-string

I'm trying to set up 301 redirects from a subdomain to the main domain, but I'm running into issues when the old urls have query strings.

The new site is running PHP as aFastCGI process. I tried using the solution listed here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/301-redirects-appending-query-string
and it works for most urls, but not when the old urls have query strings.

For example,

```
RewriteRule ^old-blog/title/?$ http://www.example.com/new-blog/title/ [L,R=301]
```

works to redirect old.example.com/old-blog/title to www.example.com/new-blog/title but I'm 
having trouble with pages that include query strings. I tried using this:

```
RewriteRule ^Default\.aspx?/?$ http://www.example.com/new-blog/ [L,R=301]
```

but a url like old.example.com/default.aspx?title redirects to www.example.com/new-blog/?title instead of just www.example.com/new-blog/

Can I stop the query strings from being appended to the new urls?

Also is there a way to just do a blanket redirect of every link that ISN'T already redirected using the first method above to www.example.com/new-blog/ ?

Not sure if it matters but the new site is running ExpressionEngine and using htaccess to remove index.php from the urls, but the htaccess rules above are on the old subdomain.